# How do I measure my pods startup, min and max CPU and Memory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, docker-desktop

I like to see how my services will work on kubernethes so I can optimize my code and set good values for request/limit on both CPU and memory.

To do that I have tried kubectl top bit ot only gives me the current usage.

```
kubectl top pod podname
```

How do I get the init, min and max usage?

If it is not possible to get all those values, is there any way to get max usage?

Comment: This might be an overkill solution but did you try [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/)? it's a UI for kubernetes with built in monitoring using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/).

Comment: yes you should add Prometheus n Grafana to have a look around that with respect to time frame

Answer (score 1):

In order to see stats you may want to use one of these [monitoring tools](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/):

1. [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor)

> Container Advisor is a great monitoring tool that provides
> container-level metrics and exposes resource usage and performance
> data from running containers. It provides quick insight into CPU
> usage, memory usage, and network receive/transmit of running
> containers. cAdvisor is embedded into the kubelet, hence you can
> scrape the kubelet to get container metrics, store the data in a
> persistent time-series store like Prometheus/InfluxDB, and then
> visualize it via Grafana.

2. [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server)

> Metrics Server is a cluster-wide aggregator of resource usage data and
> collects basic metrics like CPU and memory usage for Kubernetes nodes,
> pods, and containers. It’s used by Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and the
> Kubernetes dashboard itself, and users can access these metrics
> directly by using the kubectl top command. Metrics Server replaces
> Heapster as the primary metrics aggregator in the cluster, which has
> been marked as deprecated in the newer version of Kubernetes.

3. [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)

> Node Exporter is the Prometheus exporter for hardware and operating
> system metrics. It allows you to monitor node-level metrics such as
> CPU, memory, filesystem space, network traffic, and other monitoring
> metrics, which Prometheus scraps from a running node exporter
> instance. You can then visualize these metrics in Grafana.

4. [Kube-State-Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)

> Kube-state-metrics is an add-on agent that listens to the Kubernetes
> API server. It generates metrics about the state of the Kubernetes
> objects inside the cluster like deployments, replica sets, nodes, and
> pods.
>
> Metrics generated by kube-state-metrics are different from resource
> utilization metrics, which are primarily geared more towards CPU,
> memory, and network usage. Kube-state-metrics expose critical metrics
> about the condition of your Kubernetes cluster:
>
> - Resource requests and limits
> - Number of objects–nodes, pods, namespaces, services, deployments
> - Number of pods in a running/terminated/failed state

5. [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/)

> Prometheus is a free software application used for event monitoring
> and alerting. It records real-time metrics in a time series database
> built using a HTTP pull model, with flexible queries and real-time
> alerting

You can visualize Prometheus monitoring data with [Grafana](https://grafana.com/)
and its [dashboard collection](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards?search=pod).

You can find detailed [Monitor Your Kubernetes Cluster With Prometheus and Grafana](https://medium.com/better-programming/monitor-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-prometheus-and-grafana-1f7d0195e59) instruction how to use them together